# If one column is not valid for another column in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

### I have 3 table

```
Phone Numbers
---------------
WorkerId    CountryIso-Home Intphn Code-Home
1000              USA        1
1001              IND        2
1002              UK         3

------------
Country_ISO
--------------
Country                     Iso
United States of America    USA
India                       IND
United Kingdom              UK

-----------
Country_PhoneCode
-------------------

Country                   PhoneCode
United States of America    1
India                       2
United Kingdom              3
```

I want to write Validation sql query for
"Int Phone Code-Home is not valid for given CountryISO-Home Code.

I tried in this way..

```
SELECT WorkerId
FROM   PhoneNumbers a,
       Country_PhoneCode b
WHERE  IntPhnCode - Home != (SELECT PhoneCode
                             FROM   Country_PhoneCode i,
                                    Country_ISO j
                             WHERE  i.Country = j.Country)
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select WorkerId 
from PhoneNumbers a
join Country_ISO b on b.iso=a.CountryIso-Home
join country_phoneCode c on c.coutry=b.country
where c.PhoneCode <> a.Intphn Code-Home
```

- the JOIN Country_ISO matches the worker with their country
- the JOIN country_phoneCode gets the phone code for the country
- the WHERE clause on reports workers where the codes don't match

If you can change the database structure, move the phone code into country_ISO, since it appears to be a 1 to 1 match, so from a logical point of view, it can be a field of the ISO table